# UICollectionView: Apply dynamic width for each cell according to UIButton's text width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I know there is a lot similar topics about this problem. Although, I have tried them out first without solving my problem.

As below screenshot showed, I try to apply a horizontal scroll view with UICollectionView. And each cell contains a UIButton with dynamic text length.

The problem is the width for some of cell is wrong/short. I try the solution to get each NSString text size first, then set it in `sizeForItemAt` delegate method. However it is not working well, the text is still shrinking even I have added a padding value manually `CGSize sizeWithPadding = CGSizeMake(size.width + 30, 40)`.

After quite of hours searching and test, still no idea how to make this right. Please any advice is welcomed.

[image]

**Data source = NSString array**

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"All", @"Computer programming", @"Taylor Swift", @"Movies", @"Airplane", @"Basketball", @"Iron man", @"Football", @"ABC", @"Gong Fu", @"Dong Hua", nil]
```

**A UIView as container of the collectionView.**

```
- (void)setViews {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = CGFLOAT_MAX;
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
    self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackgroundColor;
    _collectionView.dataSource = self;
    _collectionView.delegate = self;
    [_collectionView registerClass:MenuBarCell.class forCellWithReuseIdentifier:menuBarCellID];

    [self addSubview:self.collectionView];
    
    [self.collectionView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor].active = true;
    [self.collectionView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor].active = true;
    [self.collectionView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor].active = true;
    [self.collectionView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.heightAnchor].active = true;
}

# pragma mark - collectionView dataSource
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _menuBarArray.count;
}

- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MenuBarCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:menuBarCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *model = _menuBarArray[indexPath.item];
    [cell configure:model];
    
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGSize size = [self.menuBarArray[indexPath.item] sizeWithAttributes:NULL];
    NSLog(@"size: width = %f", size.width);
    CGSize sizeWithPadding = CGSizeMake(size.width + 30, 40);
    
    return sizeWithPadding;
}
```

**My UICollectionView custom cell**

```
- (void)setViews {
    [super setViews];
    
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellowColor;
    
    // create buttons
    _button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    _button.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    _button.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    [_button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.92 alpha:1]];
    [_button setTitleColor:UIColor.labelColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_button setTitleColor:UIColor.buttonTitleHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    
    [self.contentView addSubview:_button];
    
    // set constraints
    [_button.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.centerXAnchor].active = true;
    [_button.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.centerYAnchor].active = true;
    [_button.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.widthAnchor].active = true;
    [_button.heightAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.heightAnchor].active = true;
}

- (void)configure: (NSString *)model {
    [_button setTitle:model forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: your code is that you calculate the size and set it by the delegate method. so 'sizeWithAttributes:NULL'  why use NULL, should we use a correct font attribute?

Comment: Actually I try to give it a font size or `NULL`, though it is not included in above code, but neither could give me a correct UIButton width for the title text. Please see Don Mag's answer, it works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things wrong...

Get rid of `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method -- you want to use auto-sizing cells.

Next, you don't show your code for constraining the "container" view, but I assume it's something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    menuBarView = [MenuBarView new];

    menuBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    
    [self.view addSubview:menuBarView];
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [menuBarView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [menuBarView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [menuBarView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:4.0],
        [menuBarView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:42.0],
    ]];

}
```

Your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` should be along these lines:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;

// spacing between cells
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 8.0;

// prevents last cell from being cut-off
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = layout.minimumLineSpacing;

// must have an estimated size
//  inconsequential, but needs to be less than expectd
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
```

And configure your cell class like this:

```
// I don't know what your super-class is...
//[super setViews];

self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellowColor;

// create buttons
_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
_button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
_button.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
_button.layer.masksToBounds = true;

// give the button a little top / leading / bottom / trailing "padding"
_button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 20, 8, 20);

[_button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.92 alpha:1]];
[_button setTitleColor:UIColor.labelColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button setTitleColor:UIColor.whiteColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[self.contentView addSubview:_button];

// set constraints
UIView *g = self.contentView;
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [_button.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
    [_button.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
    [_button.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:2.0],
    [_button.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:-2.0],
]];
```

Result should look like this (I gave the "container" view a blue background so we can see it):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is worked now:) First your guess is right! After a bit test I found if `layout.estimatedItemSize` is not indicated then UIButtons will not change their size automatically. And we shouldn't use `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method for auto-sizing cells, though many threads suggest to use this method... And another good thing is first to know "NEW" keyword, why I didn't see this in any code/doc, they all use alloc, init.